# Get a Google docs spreadsheet and worksheet id

Tags: javascript, google-docs, google-sheets-api

I have a problem. I can't find a simple way to get a Google docs spreadsheet and worksheet id. I'm hoping not to do this program-atically because I'm somewhat limited in my coding ability.

If it's unavoidable, what's the best way? Can Javascript do it?

Anyway, my immediate problem is:

I have the following test spreadsheet I need to update via configutations in an application called 'Run My Process' (RMP), voila:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bWlAiO_Y0C1_krvS_C5ZO73HRZZI-ewXVsy66kowpm4/edit?authkey=CNTQxtgN&hl=en_US&authkey=CNTQxtgN#gid=0

I need to know the `spreadsheet id` and the `worksheet id` so I can stuff them into the following string used by the RMP parameter.

feeds/list/**${spreadsheet_id}**/**${worksheet_id}**/private/full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the Google Apps Script in getting the spreadsheed ID. As you can see in your example "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bWlAiO_Y0C1_krvS_C5ZO73HRZZI-ewXVsy66kowpm4/edit?authkey=CNTQxtgN&hl=en_US&authkey=CNTQxtgN#gid=0" the id of the spreadsheet is the part between key= and #gid=. So you can retrieve this by using this code.

```
function getId() {
  Browser.msgBox('Spreadsheet key: ' + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId());
}
```